# No network after Windows Server upgrade

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012-r2, upgrade

Last night I started upgrading a server from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2012 R2.
This morning checking if everything went well, the network card says "unidentified network" and "no Internet access". DHCP does not work, and neither does ping when I switch back to static IP. There is nevertheless incoming and outgoing traffic.
I tried to update the drivers of the network card as well as its firmware, but nothing changes.
I tried to connect a USB network adapter, but the problem remains the same; the problem seems to come from Windows and not the card or drivers.
So I tried to run the command "netsh winsock reset" and then restart, but here it does not work.

I do not know what to do while it is imperative that this server works before Monday morning.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT 1:

I tried that without more results:

```
netsh int ip reset C:\logreset.txt
netsh int tcp set heuristics disabled
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
netsh int tcp set global rss=enabled
netsh int tcp show global
```

Comment: DHCP does not work? local DHCP server or does it not receive an IP from DHCP server?

Comment: Any VLAN settings on the switch port? It's possible that the required VLAN tagging was lost with the upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Murphy hit again!
During the night the port of the switch to which the server was connected is dead.
The switch communicates with the connected equipment but the port is isolated from all the rest of the network ...

Coincidence or not? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Might occur if Windows Firewall considers your network a *public* network.

In my experience,

- you install Windows Server 2012 R2
- Windows Server 2012 R2 defaults to public network
- you update, install antimalware, etc
- you promote to DC

BUT

- Windows Server 2012 R2 *continues* to treat the network as public.
  To fix, restart the Network Location Awareness service.
  After a restart, Windows Server 2012 R2 *correctly* detects your network as a domain network, and the right firewall profile activates.